# No results while using save of JPA in unit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jpa-2.0

I am having a weird situation while doing some unit testing. When I am using save method of JPA it's not returning anything, neither it's throwing any error.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MerchantRepoTest {

    private Long personID = 12333333l;
    @Mock
    private ABC abcRepo;
    @Mock
    private Person personRepo;
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Test
    public void testPerson() {

        System.out.println("Starting................");
        Person person = new Person();

        TxnLimit txnLimit = new TxnLimit();
        txnLimit.setType("MONTHY");
        txnLimit.setValue(1000000000l);
        List<TxnLimit> txnLimits = new ArrayList<>();
        txnLimits.add(txnLimit);
        person.setTxnLimits(gson.toJson(txnLimits));

        ABC abc = new ABC();
        abc.setPersonId(personId);
        Metadata metaData = new Metadata();
        metaData.setDescription("DESC");
        metaData.setName("MUKUL");
        person.setMetadata(metaData);
        person.setId(personId);
        person.setType("Food");
        person.accountToken("hgh-hhjds-hdbhj");

        try {
            Person per1=  personRepo.save(merchant);
            ABC savedA = abcRepo.save(abc);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("SAVED @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            System.out.println("ID1 + " + per1.getId());
            System.out.println("###############");
        }  catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        Person found = personRepo.findOne(personID);
        System.out.println("FOUND..." + found);
        String name = found.getMetadata().getName();
        Assert.assertEquals(name, "MUKUL");
    }
}
```

My test case is failing and I am getting NullPointerException at             `String name = found.getMetadata().getName();`, As I am getting found as null. I have tried to print middle steps and out of my surprise, something is wrong, while saving the details.

I am able to print                 `System.out.println("SAVED @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");` line but after that line I am not getting next two lines. i am also not getting any exception in **catch** block. The next message I am getting on my screen is roll-back of transaction.

```
2018-10-31 18:17:14.759 [] [] [Test worker] INFO  t.context.transaction.TransactionContext:106 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@780636f3 testClass = MerchantRepoTest, testInstance = com.paytm.paylite.merchant.repo.MerchantRepoTest@735dc46, testMethod = testOK1@MerchantRepoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@8006101 testClass = MerchantRepoTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.paytm.paylite.merchant.MerchantServiceApp}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@503407f6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@73b73c3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6bc7795, [ImportsContextCustomizer@4342f78e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@67aa907e, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@50394650, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@63f5badc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@40ec0c87]; rollback [true]
Starting................
...
...
..
SAVED @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
FOUND...null
2018-10-31 18:17:15.829 [] [] [Test worker] INFO  t.context.transaction.TransactionContext:140 - Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@780636f3 testClass = MerchantRepoTest, testInstance = com.paytm.paylite.merchant.repo.MerchantRepoTest@735dc46, testMethod = testOK1@MerchantRepoTest, testException = java.lang.NullPointerException, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@8006101 testClass = MerchantRepoTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.paytm.paylite.merchant.MerchantServiceApp}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@503407f6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@73b73c3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6bc7795, [ImportsContextCustomizer@4342f78e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@67aa907e, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@50394650, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@63f5badc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
```

I am unable to figure out what may be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you try autowiring `personRepo` and `abcRepo` instead of mocking

Comment: @Thiru : when I am trying to autowire this it is showing this error. No transactional EntityManager found. I tried by wrpping that piece of code in transactional annotation

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your repo is mocked. This means that its methods are not called. If you really want to test saving to your DB, you can autowire `personRepo` and `abcRepo` (but you should do that only for integration tests). Better way for unit testing is that you change behaviour of mocks by `when(abcRepo.findOne(any()).thenReturn(...);` By this way you will test behaviour of your tested class, not repo exactly.

Comment: Do you think your answer explains why:  `System.out.println("SAVED @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");` is called but `System.out.println("ID1 + " + per1.getId());` doesn't get called?

Comment: It does get called, in the output above is 'FOUND...null'. Person is null in this case, because repo is mocked (findOne is not mocked -> returns null).

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring personRepo and abcRepo would not be smart in unit tests, mocking is the way to go.
After mocking those classes, you should also mock the behavior of every method you use.
For example:

```
Mockito.when(personRepo.save(person)).thenReturn(person);
```

or if that doesn't work, try:

```
Mockito.when(personRepo.save(person)).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        Person p = (Person) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
        p.setId(1);
        //create here object you expect to be returned by save method using setters.
        return p;
    });
```

Put those lines before the try block. And google on how to mock in java unit tests, you can find great examples etc.